# Drawing line on a CALayer in OSx

Tags: objective-c, macos, drawing, calayer, paint

I would like to know if you can help me with painting on layers.

The situation is this

I am programming on this kind of screen http://multitouch.com, 12 touches simultaneously.
In the app I am developing, I can manage multiple images. I can rotate, scale an move at the same time all images (maximum 12 touches on the screen!)
To accomplish this I use ONLY layers for performances. 
Every image is represented by a CALayer, then I create my CALayer's and set the image as its 'contents'. The hierarchy is this.

I have only a NSView.

- NSView "Container_View"
- CALayer "Images_Layer" as sublayer of the "Container_View" layer (they have the same frame)
- CALayer "Img_1_Layer", CALayer "Img_2_Layer", CALayer "Img_3_Layer", etc as sublayer of "Images_Layer"

As I told you before, I can rotate, scale and move my Images.

Double tap on a single image, I lock the whole screen, I can still rotate and move the image but ONLY with 2 fingers.

Now I would like that user can draw with 1 finger on this image.

The main problem is that I have not experience with graphics and all example on internet are about draw line on view.

The question is How to draw with a finger on a CALayer. I have only CALayer, I cannot have NSView

Many thantk in advance, Sergio

---

Hi Mazyod, the CALayer class that provides the Image is very big.

Please try to understand this context

MainWindow as root naturally

NSViewController called MainViewController with a custom NSView as root view - this view is called Container and it's set as contentView of the MainWindow

CALayer called Images_Layer - it's a layer added as SubLayer of the Container's layer

CALayer called Img_Layer - it's a layer added as SubLayer of the Images_Layer (I have one of this for each image, set as contents naturally, then an CGImageRef)

When I click on an Image (ImgLayer), 3 methods are fired as usual:

onTouchPointDown - with x, y etc
onTouchPointMove - with x, y etc
onTouchPointUp - with x, y etc

Comment: You say your interest is in OS X.  Then you are talking about drawing a figure or a line with a finger?  Tapping an image?  What you say doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry for my english, I wanted to explain how my app works. Yes I want to draw with 1 finger on a CALayer that contains an image as its 'contents'.

Let's say that I have my CustomLayerImage with 3 method:

TouchBegan
TouchMove
TouchEnd

Comment: I would suggest you show some of the code you have so far, so we can start from there. FYI, drawing on a `CALayer` is exactly the same as drawing on a view, with a single difference: instead of using `drawRect:` to draw, you'd use `drawInContext:`

Comment: Hi Mazyod, I edited my question, read above please

Comment: The scenario is like this, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0-dWFZglfs
from the minute 1.25, I can do exactly the same. All images, in my case, are all CALayer. Now, imagine that if I double tap on a single image, all screen get locked except for that image. A custom bar is shown close to the image where the user can select a color and draw on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found.

- set the layer's delegate
- override this method in the delegate
- call layer setNeedDisplay method when you need

`-` `(void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx`

`{`

```
NSGraphicsContext *gc = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:ctx flipped:NO];
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:gc];

// draw points with bezier path

[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
```

`}`